# dont work select single item and highlight listview android

Tags: android, xml, listview

I'm selecting

```
lst_Center.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

and adding a `listView`:

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

and `LinearLayout`:

```
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
```

And adding a `list_selector.xml`:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/Blue" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/Red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
```

But it's not working, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Create list_background.xml in drawable folder and add below lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/anycolor" />
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/anycolor" />
 <item android:drawable="@color/anycolor" />
</selector>
```

Set background for your ListView.

```
android:background="@drawable/list_background"
```

If you want to highlight only the selecting list item means then you should set the background for textview. For that just go through about custom adapter.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Updated the answer. Accept the answer if it is useful.